# Does something prevent two thunderbolt3 displays from connecting into a port replicator that feeds into 1 thunderbolt 3 port?

Tags: thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I have two external monitors, neither have a native thunderbolt 3 port. One is HDMI, and one is a mystery to me, it's small and sort of squarish with a notch. They both have a company supplied thunderbolt 3 adapter. I bought [this docking station](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CZPV8DF) so I can connect both of these monitors in. But it only had one functional thunderbolt 3 port; the other is meant for a cable to go to the laptop. So for the HDMI monitor, I bought a cheap 8 dollar converter from DisplayPort to HDMI. It doesn't matter, it didn't work. Only one monitor works. I have to plug the other monitor directly into the mac with the  thunderbolt connector. So I thought I'd look for a docking station that can handle two Thunderbolt 3 monitors, but they don't seem to exist. My question is, is there a fundamental limitation that prevents two Thunderbolt 3 monitors from ultimately connecting into one thunderbolt port on the macbook pro?

Here are some things I was asked, maybe it helps answer the question
[image: system]
[image: displays]

None of these monitors have a native thunderbolt3 cable.  They all have adapters attached.  I didn't buy the adapters, it was given to me, as was this mac.

Comment: DisplayPort is hardly "Mac-related".  It's a standard, it's widely used.  No, there's not any fundamental limitation, but it's likely that neither monitor is actually Thunderbolt.  What are the monitors?  That is a *very* good dock, although it is rather pricey.

Comment: Please add specific information about the mac model with OS version, the monitors and the cable you bought. A simple DisplayPort to HDMI cable does not work; it needs to be an active cable, as stated in the CalDigits specs: https://www.caldigit.com/ts3-plus/

Comment: Yes, I scrolled all the way to the bottom of that document and saw in bold that it needs to be an active adapter.  I one clicked the prior adapter so you can imagine how much effort I put into this research.  I think this maybe the answer; I just one clicked an "active" adapter.